# Can't get project that uses JUnit4 to work in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, junit, compiler-errors

I have a very simple project with the following structure:

```
myProject
--src
  --rectangles
    --Utils
    --Main
--test
  --rectangles
    --Tests
```

I've marked the folders accordingly, added the library and there are no errors in any of the classes or test files. However, when trying to run anything I get the following error:

```
Error:java: /test/myProject: does not exist
```

Where `myProject` is the project folder.

I've been trying various settings and searched everywhere but I still can't see what's wrong. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2 under Ubuntu, and the Java version is 8.

[image]

Comment: there is no folder named `myProject` within `test`... so the message _"Error:java: /test/myProject: does not exist"_ is clear

Comment: I understand, but I do not intend to have such a folder. Why does it require a folder with that name?

Comment: Is this a compilation or an execution error? The question label indicates the first, while your wording the second

Comment: It doesn't work in either case, since it tries to Make the project (this is when the error occurs).

Comment: in the branch `test/dir/Tests` , is `dir/Tests` a Java package?

Comment: make aware: every directory within `myProject/src` is a package name. Same for directories within `myProject/test`

Comment: I guess you're completely on a meander, concerning the directory structure. I've made an edit to your post. According to your note, I've replaced _dir_ with _rectangles_ . The edit isn't approved yet

Comment: @JimHawkins Thank you for your help. The reason I'm being hesitant about the actual names of the files and the content is because this is related to homework - although in this question the problem is strictly technical (I did not ask about the code itself, which is the subject of homework). I've barely used Java before and I do not know its subtleties. The tests file is provided and it's part of the same package as the rest of the source classes. I haven't covered much material on packages yet, so I am a bit lost on your questions.

Comment: OK David :-) so tell me, what is the name of the test class, and what is the it's package? Look at the line of test file (*.java) which begins with _"package"_

Comment: The test class is called *TestSuite*. The first line is *package rectangles;*. This is also the case for every source file that I have.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Your project should look very similar

Comment: I would appreciate getting some feedback, because I spent some time solving your problem... that's the way stack overflow works

Answer (score 0):

Based on your last comment, I've created a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which has this structure:

[image]

The `TestSuite` is placed in the same package as the "production mode" classes (`BBox` `Main`, and `Square`), but not in the same directory.

The folder `test` was created manually, and I marked it as "Tests" in IntelliJs project structure.

These are the relevant project settings:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I understand your point and thanks for the answer. In the meantime, I was able to achieve the correct behavior by using Import Project instead of simply opening (although I still don't know why that makes a difference). The only difference between my project structure and your latest post is that  I did not have "Inherit project compile output path" selected, instead I provided a different path, which should still not affect the result.